# Vertical aligning div inside ionic view content

Tags: css, ionic-framework

I am trying to vertical align div inside ionic view. I refer to [this codepen](http://codepen.io/hannuraina/pen/qoalx). The sample in this codepen works for ionic view without header. However, if i include the header as follow, it does not correctly vertically align.

What can i do to make it vertically align in such a case?

```
<body ng-controller="AppCtrl as ctrl">
    <ion-header-bar align-title="left" class="bar-positive">
  <div class="buttons">
    <button class="button" ng-click="doSomething()">Left Button</button>
  </div>
  <h1 class="title">Title!</h1>
  <div class="buttons">
    <button class="button">Right Button</button>
  </div>
</ion-header-bar>
   <ion-content has-header="true" padding="true">
    <div class="row row-center">
      <div class="col col-center">
        You need to login
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">
        <button class="button button-block button-positive">
          Go to Login
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </ion-content>

  </body>
```

Comment: I can't see any difference even after adding header. Can you please elaborate your problem?

Answer (score 0):

```
.center1{
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -moz-box-direction: normal;
  -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
  -moz-box-orient: horizontal;
  -webkit-flex-direction: row;
  -ms-flex-direction: row;
  flex-direction: row;
  -webkit-flex-wrap: nowrap;
  -ms-flex-wrap: nowrap;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -moz-box-pack: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-align-content: stretch;
  -ms-flex-line-pack: stretch;
  align-content: stretch;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -moz-box-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

Add following class to your CSS.